# Elgg Custom Table Handling

Tags: elgg

In Elgg how to access user table which is not created by the Elgg . `In MySQL i have certain s tables that i need to access and display it in the user profile, how to create PLUGIN for that.`

I have few tables other than elgg , with one-to-many relationships, that having few custom mysql query, these query will fetch data from the table and show on the UI, similarity if the user want to insert the record he can do that also,User is able to perform CRUD Operation.

I need a basic tutorial for this for creating Plugin/widgets that can handle CRUD operation on custom tables

Comment: I think you might want to improve this question. I don't really know what I should answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes  first download some basic example plugin, and then create pages, actions,  etc, and in start.php you can create some menus (site menu,top menu) or even hook to some event(signup,login,  there are thousads of event) and then use your non elgg tables to do stuff)

you can refer  engine/lib/database.php for your non elgg tables.

$q = "SELECT * FROM table ";
    $data = get_data($q);

Answer (score 0):

Like this. `vendor\elgg\elgg\engine\classes\Elgg\Database`.

```
function getByPhone($phonenumber) {
    $phonenumber = sanitise_string($phonenumber);
    $access = _elgg_get_access_where_sql();
    $query = "SELECT e.* FROM {$this->CONFIG->dbprefix}entities e
      JOIN {$this->CONFIG->dbprefix}users_entity u ON e.guid = u.guid
      WHERE phone_number = '$phonenumber' AND $access";
    return _elgg_services()->db->getData($query, 'entity_row_to_elggstar');
}
```